# Show that $f$ is integrable $\implies $ $f$ finite a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Show that $f:\mathbb R^d\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is integrable $\implies $ $f$ finite a.e.

**My attempts**
I wanted to use Borel-Cantelli lemma, but my construction doesn't look good for it since I did like this:

Let $A=\{x\mid |f(x)|=\infty \}$ and suppose that $m(A)>0$. Define $A_n=\{x\mid |f(x)|>n\}$. We have that $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$ for all $n$, and thus $$\lim_{n\to\infty }m(A_n)=m\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n\right)=m(A)>0.$$

How can I continue ?

Comment: Integrate over $A_{N}$ to show the integral is unbounded for all k bigger than N.

Comment: It seems that the question does not make sense. By the very definition, $f$ is a function with domain $\mathbb{R^d}$ and co-domain $\mathbb{R}$ and hence $f$ is finite everywhere (we do not even need measurability).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allready there. Observe that: $$\int |f|dm\geq\int |f|1_Adm=(+\infty)\times m(A)=+\infty$$ Showing that $f$ is *not* integrable. This is proved on base of the assumption that $f$ is *not* finite a.e..

Comment: Proof is not required because the co-domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$. Hence $f$ is finite everywhere.

Comment: @Danny Indeed, but that I am convinced that is some typo of the OP.